# Is "No" a complete sentence

Tags: sentence

I'm aware **No** is what is called a "sentence word". Does that mean that on its own, it is a "complete sentence"?

Please state the reason for your answer, i.e. do not simply answer "Yes" or "No"

Comment: Yes (because the rest of the sentence is *implied*).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has been answered before, as well as showing no research.

Comment: @Tim Ward Or 'no' (because the missing implied part deletes the subject and verb that is considered necessary by some: they would call this a 'sentence substitute').)

Comment: Related: [Shortest complete sentence in English](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/258/shortest-complete-sentence-in-english) and [Shortest correct sentence in English- use of contractions](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/126774/shortest-correct-sentence-in-english-use-of-contractions)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is just "no." a valid sentence?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/60765/is-just-no-a-valid-sentence)

Answer (score 4):

Yes. (See what I did there?)

The sentence forms a complete thought, therefore is a complete sentence.

Also see this: [Shortest complete sentence in English](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/258/shortest-complete-sentence-in-english)

Comment: Hello. IncludeGrammar. (1) This question has been asked and answered here before. (2) You are choosing one definition of 'sentence' in your answer. It is not the only one.

Answer (score 1):

'Yes' and 'no' are interjections.  ('No' can also be a determiner, but we'll skip that.)  Interjections are like emojis.  'Yes' is a shortcut for 'that is true', and 'no' for 'that is not true'.  When the shortcut says everything that a clause would say, the clause can be omitted, leaving only the shortcut.  This is still a sentence, because it gets processed as though the clause was there (even though 'yes' and 'no' do not actually get stored in memory - they merely adjust the trust weight of the referent clause, just as would repeating or negating the clause explicitly).

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Evidence: To be conjoined with "and", constituents must be of the same grammatical category.  Then since in

> No, and I'm never going to.

the second part, "I'm never going to" is a sentence, "No" must be a sentence, too.

Comment: I was brought up to believe that a sentence had to have a verb, in order to be a sentence. So in this case I call it a sentence, but pretend that a lot of words are elided. e.g. *Are you going to the pub tonight?* Answer: *No (I am not going to the pub tonight)*.

Comment: @WS2 We may be able to bring evidence to bear on whether there are elided words.  Compare *"Did you have any beer? No, and it wasn't Bud." with "Did you have any beer? Yes, and it was Bud."  In the second example, "it" refers back to "some beer" in the understood part of "Yes (I did have some beer)".  See https://books.google.com/books?id=k6-C5AWWqjQC&pg=PA344&lpg=PA344&dq=grinder+missing+antecedent&source=bl&ots=uOhA4LauVc&sig=NX-QyTq6Yym6oxPKPpl3EB863mA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi_qOCA1PDKAhWIjZQKHQ_QBmQQ6AEIPjAI#v=onepage&q=grinder%20missing%20antecedent&f=false